# Clash of Clans keeps crashing!

Tags: clash-of-clans

So my clash of clans keeps crashing whenever I tap the friends tab to view my friends list. By the way I'm using BlueStacks to play Clash of Clans. Can someone please tell me why this happen? and how I can fix it. Thanks

Comment: Note that BlueStacks is not supported in any way by Supercell.

Comment: I highly recommend you switch over to andyroid its actually kept up to date with android on phones, bluestacks is a hunk of junk that is so outdated

Answer (score 1):

It could be that because your using a app player, the game doesn't run properly. I don't know what could be the cause, but it could be a problem with the game installation. Get a data transfer code (In game settings), and reinstall the game.
Once you have the game again, use the code in the settings.

There also could be a unlikely chance that Bluestacks is not supposed to go in the friends tab because of missing apps, or files. In this case, I can't help you.

If these aren't the case, it might be something with your friends list that causes it to be accessible (which is probably not possible).

Sorry if none of this helps.